# How do I run a .flv in full resolution, using the video class?

Tags: flash, flv

I have an application, implemented using the Flash Video class. How do I make it run a .flv video in full resolution? All videos are running in the default 320x240 resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [documentation](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/media/Video.html#Video%28%29):  You can instantiate the Video object with a given width or height.  [Here](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/media/Video.html#videoWidth) is the way to find out the original width and height of the file you are playing: Use the videoWidth and videoHeight properties.

```
video.width = video.videoWidth;
video.height = video.videoHeight;
```

Comment: I know that. I want to calculate the resolution of the video and then run it in full resolution. I have many videos that need to be played, all have a different resolution.

Comment: Same page, different paragraph. http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/media/Video.html#videoWidth  I have changed the answer above accordingly.